# Migrate Dynamics CRM Configuration File Settings for use with ASPNet5 / MVC6

Tags: dynamics-crm, asp.net-core, configuration-files, dnx

## No answer required - experience documented for others

### I wasted significant time and hope to save others the trouble

**TLDR;**
*If you are trying to use Microsoft Dynamics CRM with an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 (dnx / vnext) application, don't overthink it - just use the existing web.config file!*

Personally, I got so wrapped up in the new configuration paradigm that the now obvious approach of just using the good 'ol web.config file to store the required configuration settings did not occur to me.

I was trying to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM; everything compiled and executed until I hit code that tries to create a CRM context generated using CrmSvcUtil.exe.

> var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm");

The runtime error I got was, "A configuration element with the name 'Xrm' under the 'contexts' collection does not exist."

This simply means that there is something wrong with the configuration file.  Now, I had an existing console application with the proper (working) configuration settings and I was trying to simply port them over to this vNext solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.xrm.client" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Configuration.CrmSection, Microsoft.Xrm.Client"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Xrm" connectionString="Server=https://myserver.crm.dynamics.com; Domain=; Username=myUsername@domain.com;Password=myPassword"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.xrm.client>
    <contexts default="Xrm">
      <add name="Xrm" type="Xrm.XrmServiceContext, Xrm" connectionStringName="Xrm"/>
    </contexts>
  </microsoft.xrm.client>
</configuration>
```

My mistake, however, was a misguided attempt to use the new configuration paradigm and import the "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Xml" NuGet package.  Then, I added the configuration file containing the necessary settings during Startup():  *Again, this isn't the right approach; use web.config instead*:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(env.WebRootPath)
                .AddXmlFile("config.xml")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me writing out the speculation here that the CRM dll's have no clue about the new IConfigurationSource approach.  I knew there had to be another way and then my Friday night tired brain finally clicked..."Hey, I see a web.config file...I wonder if that would work."  Yes, it does.